# Trying to pass arguments through initComponent to item array

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I have a form with combos in it, and I am trying to figure out an easy way of passing the combo values through to the combo widget.

Basically I am passing through an array to my form like so :

```
    var contentPanel = Ext.create('MyForm', {
        countryCodesForCombo: _this.countryCodesForCombo,
    });
```

This means the data comes through the **initComponent** method.

```
Ext.define('MyForm', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',

    initComponent : function (){

        var cCodes = this.countryCodesForCombo;

        this.callParent();
    },
    items: [
        {
            fieldLabel: 'Hi',
            xtype: 'combobox',
            name: 'land',
            displayField:'name',
            store: {
                fields: ['name'],
                data: this.countryCodesForCombo // <--- want to get country codes somehow here
            }
        }
    ]
});
```

However the values can't get to the item objects.

Basically my question is, how do I get values passed through the **initComponent** method into the items array?

Comment: Think about the order of evaluation. The whole RHS of the object needs to be evaluated before it's ever even passed to define. The class doesn't exist, let alone an instance.

Answer (score 2):

Your store doesnt look right. You have to create a store object.

This will work:

```
Ext.define('MyForm', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',

    initComponent : function (){

        this.store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
            fields: ['name'],
            data: this.countryCodesForCombo
        });

        Ext.apply(this, {

                    items: [{

                        fieldLabel: 'Hi',
                        xtype: 'combobox',
                        queryMode: 'local',
                        name: 'land',
                        displayField:'name',
                        store: this.store                    
                    }]
        });

        this.callParent();
    },

});
```

Here is a fiddle link too: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/9ru

Comment: my store is OK. I was just wondering if there was a cleaner way of passing values to the items. Using Ext.apply(this... ) just seems a bit messy to me.

Comment: I think `Ext.apply(this,{..})` is OK if you are not mixing it a lot. But i had headache too until i got used to it.